# How to implement count-up on the website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a [wedding site](https://www.bunlongheng.com/wedding), I used to add the **count-down** feature in it, now since the day pass. The count-down no longer works. ‍♂️

[image]

Now I want to make it increase instead.

Ex.

I want to show :

> We have been married for `364 days 23 hours 38 mins 23 seconds`

*second shall keep increasing every second as it goes by*

The days/hours/minutes/second should be reflected from the wedding day: `3/26/2018`

---

count-down

```
$(".countdown").countdown({
        date: "May 27 2018 8:00:00", // add the countdown's end date (i.e. 3 november 2012 12:00:00)
        format: "on" // on (03:07:52) | off (3:7:52) - two_digits set to ON maintains layout consistency
      });
```

How would one go about and implement something like this?

Comment: Maybe you can tell/show how did the countdown worked? It may be a simple adjustment to the same code.

Comment: I added it. I used countdown.js :  https://www.bunlongheng.com/wedding_/js/countdown.js

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the count down timer js file. You will see this:

```
if(eventDate <= currentDate) {
    return false;
}
```

so we would need to start by removing this. I would start there and work through the changes.

And change this line:

```
days = Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)); //calculate the number of days
```

To :

```
days = Math.abs(Math.floor(seconds / (60 * 60 * 24)));
```

Comment: I removed that now, I see this : https://i.imgur.com/Zpxvyiy.png

Comment: Ok, forget the `-` does that number seem correct?

Comment: Try changing the days as described above.

Comment: Thanks for trying, and answering.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the code you had linked to, and simply changed the order of the dates:

```
seconds = eventDate - currentDate;
```

to

```
seconds = currentDate - eventDate;
```

I also created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gxajcfs1/) for you to try it.

Comment: Very simple suggestion.

Comment: How do you call what I am trying to do ? `count-up` ?